# Excel: In what order a word appear

Tags: excel

I have this case right here. The table below is what I expect, but it's originally without a formula.

[image: This is a capture from my excel for what I expect]

***Info for the pic:***
On the green cell, i'd like to find two criteria from two different cells: "Car"  & "Ford", in what line are they?

The blue cell is the second example. It is the same but different criteria. So I want to do this to build a product number with my own formula that I already built, except this last things.

***My question is:*** 
What formula that can do that. I did a full day research on the internet, google and youtube. But I don't get and answer. And I'm not an expert in a excel. I only did and googling all the things I did in excel. So please help me find out how.

Thank You

Comment: Add a helper column which concatenates the first two columns, then use countif() on that column.

Comment: I already consider that before, but my column is too much already. So if there is a way without to do that, I prefer that way. But thank you so much anyway, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the formula shown is entered in E2 and filled down.

**Note** this is an array formula, so use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter it.

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly on that example, but how do I put array inside another formula? For example I can't do this:

=TEXT({=SUM((I$3:I3=I3)*(J$3:J3=J3))},"000")

Thank you so much for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: You do not enter the `{}` - Excel will do that for you (around the *whole* formula) when you use Ctrl+Shift+Enter. See my updated screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Perfect

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest you look into Pivot Tables.  They do exactly what you want and probably more.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576